# increase size of mouseleave area

Tags: javascript, mouseenter, mouseleave

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/RBJ9R/1504/>
```

I would like the mouseleave trigger area to increase in size to include the image as well as the original mouseenter area (gray box). I would like the user to be able to still see the image if they mouse over into the image area.

thanks!

```
#slender-trigger {
background-color: #CCC;
height: 100px;
width: 120px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 50px;
position: absolute;
}
#slender {
font-family: 'Strait', sans-serif;
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
border: thin dotted #F00;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 120px;
display: none;  
}


<div class="purchasing-tips">
<div id="slender-trigger">nnnn</div> 
<div id="slender" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/120/100/people); height: 100px; width: 120px; border: 1px solid black;">sadfasdf</div>
</div>

$("#slender-trigger").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $("#slender").show();

}).on("mouseleave", function() {
  $("#slender").hide();
});
```

Comment: Can you also add the code in the question? if something ever happens to jsfiddle, then a lot of other users who see this post on SO looking for an answer will be frustrated

Comment: im new to SO. how do i add code to the entry? it keeps blocking me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply write this way:

```
    $("#slender-trigger, #slender").on("mouseenter", function() {
      $("#slender").show();

}).on("mouseleave", function() {
      $("#slender").hide();
});
```

[here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/banzay52/o0cLt6ba/1/)

Comment: if my answer is useful for you, pls click UP-arrow on the left of my answer

Comment: i am brand new to SO, and it says I dont have the 'reputation' yet to upvote you.. when i get it I will. Thanks!